# $L^1$ norm of Fourier transform of subset sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, exponential-sums, circle-method

Let $n_1,\dots,n_k$ be a set of $k$ natural numbers less than $N$, with $k = (1- \delta) \log_2 N$ for $\delta$ relatively small. Let $e(x) = e^{ 2\pi i x}$, as usual.

Assume that $$\int_0^1\prod_{j=1}^k \left|1+ e\left( n_j\alpha\right)\right|^2 d\alpha\leq C 2^k$$ for some reasonable $C$ (even $C=1$ would be fine).

How large can $$\int_0^1\prod_{j=1}^k \left|1+ e\left( n_j\alpha\right)\right| d\alpha$$ be? Can it approach the Cauchy-Schwarz bound of $C 2^k$?

In the special case where the $n_j$ are all distinct powers of $2$, Bourgain proved a bound of the form $N^{ O( \delta\log (1/\delta))}$ (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0398v1.pdf, Lemma 2)  which is considerably better than the trivial bound for $\delta$ small.

Are things much worse for other sets? I don't know what to expect the worst-case examples to look like. I don't think random sets do very well here, for instance.

This question was inspired by [this question](https://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/prime-subset-sums/) of Jordan Ellenberg's, though even a very strong result on this question would be very far from answering Jordan's.

Comment: There seems to be a small but non-trivial intersection between this question and my old question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123788/on-the-l1-norm-of-certain-exponential-sums . Perhaps the nice comments and answer I got there may be of some utility...